# CS50 SQL codespace probelm

Tags: sqlite, cs50

I am trying to submit my assignment for CS50 SQL. I get prompted by the following error, which states that I am in another directory, which is not the case.
The error that I get:
You are currently in: /workspaces/148092389, did you perhaps intend another directory?
Submission cancelled.

I have successfully tried by "lm" to get into the directory of cyberchase. But I still get this error.

[Here is a screenshot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujoZZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Explorer" pane on the left is pointing to the `cyberchase` directory. The `check50` in Terminal is being run from the workspace home directory. It should be run within the `cyberchase` sub-directory. Use `cd cyberchase` to change directories before initiating `check50`.